# how to broadcast location data isung an iBeacon?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, raspbian

I was able to build an iBeacon using a Raspberry pi B+ and I would like to broadcast some location data but I got no idea how to input the said data in my Beacon.
Any idea is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as I know the iBeacon is not broadcasting location data - just it's ID that can be correlated to location-data

Answer (score 1):

When broadcasting an iBeacon transmission, you basically have three usable fields to work with:

- ProimityUUID (16 bytes)
- major (2 bytes)
- minor (2 bytes)

But because you have to know the ProximityUUID up front on iOS, if you are detecting the beacon on iOS devices, you can't change that field arbitrarily, so you really only have the major and minor to play with (a total of 4 bytes.)  On Android, Linux and OSX, you can see all iBeacon transmissions regardless of the ProximityUUID, so you have a total of 20 bytes to work with.

Four bytes is not very much to encode location information, but you could put the latitude in the two byte major and the longitude in the two byte minor.  For example, if you were to store longitude (0-360 degrees) in a two byte value of 0-65535, each unit increment would be 360/65536 = 0.0054931640625 degrees (about 611 meters at the equator.)  This kind of encoding would allow you to transmit the Raspberry Pi's location via an iBeacon at +/306 meters.

Another alternative, as @Paulw11 suggests is to just transmit the UUID, major and minor to mobile devices, and then use this three-part identifier as a key to look up the actual location information in an online database via a web service.  To do this, your Raspberry Pi has to have internet connectivity and you have to build the web service.

In case you are wondering how to get location information on a Raspberry Pi without GPS, if you have a WiFi dongle and internet connectivity, then the [Google Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/) works great.  You scan for visible access points, then send them to the Google service, and it responds with a latitude and longitude.  It is free for development use at low volumes.

Comment: Thank you @davidyoung for your answer. I'll try to play with those 20 bytes and get back to you

Comment: Hi @davidyoung. I've been trying to use the 20 bytes during the past days to broadcast what I want but it didn't work. So my question is the following: say you have the following command `sudo tools/hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 E2 0A 39 F4 73 F5 4B C4 A1 2F 17 D1 AD 07 A9 61 00 00 00 00 C8 00` , how can you change it so the RP is both an iBeacon and broadcasts the following coordinates (just an example): **40.689261, -74.044489** ? Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Using my proposed encoding algorithm above with your example latitude and longitude, you store these in the major and minor field, which come right after the  `E2 0A 39 F4 73 F5 4B C4 A1 2F 17 D1 AD 07 A9 61` ProximityUUID.  To encode 40.689261, you take 40.689261/0.0054931640625 = 7407 (0x1cef).  To encode  -74.044489, you take -74.044489/0.0054931640625 = -13479 (0xcb59).  This makes the byte sequence be `...E2 0A 39 F4 73 F5 4B C4 A1 2F 17 D1 AD 07 A9 61 1C EF CB 59...`

Answer (score 0):

An iBeacon doesn't broadcast a location.  It just broadcasts a ID and two 16 bit numbers known as the major and minor numbers.

When an application detects a beacon it can use these pieces of information along with some database - either internal or on a server - to identify a 'location' - This could be a store, department branch and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my question was to know if it is possible to write some Lat and Lng into thhose Minor and Major bytes